# How do I add another provider and fill its variables with values from Firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I followed a tutorial on how to use a wrapper around my app to monitor the status of the user's authentication. This had me using `StreamProvider`. I now want to add a new `provider` to hold some global variables (2 string fields). These variables should hold the user's authenticated UID (from Firebase Auth) and their username (from Firestore). I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/theotherdev-s/starting-with-flutter-a-simple-guide-for-provider-401b25957989) to add it, but it's not working.

How do I add this `provider` and fill it with values from Firebase Auth and Firestore?

**Current Code:**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseHelper.init();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<ModelUser?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The section of the tutorial that I want to add:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
      create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
        builder: (context, themeProvider, child) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Provider Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark),
          ),
          home: MainScaffold(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The provider I want to use:**

```
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String currentUID = '';
  String currentUsername = '';
}
```

**Wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<ModelUser?>(context);

    //return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

**What I've tried so far:**

Update: the error was because of something else. The app runs, now all I need is to know how to fill those provider variables with values from Firebase.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalsProvider>(
      create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
      child: Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globalsProvider, child) => StreamProvider<ModelUser?>.value(
          value: AuthService().user,
          initialData: null,
          child: GetMaterialApp(
            title: 'MyApp',
            home: Wrapper(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi does my answer help? if yes acknowledge it and if not then we can solve it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `GlobalsProvider` and serve it through Provider as follows:

**`Update`** : Yes you can this provider without Context I have updated the code

**globals_provider.dart**:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String currentUID = '';
  String currentUsername = '';

GlobalsProvider() {
    userGlobals();
  }

  Future<void> userGlobals() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      currentUID = user.uid;
      final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
      currentUsername = userData.data()?['username'] ?? '';
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here userName does not exist on `auth.currentUser` so I have assumed you  are storing user details in users collections and storing it with `auth.currentUser` as a documentId but if you mean to assign displayName to the currentUsername then you can do that same like with currentUID:
`currentUsername = user.displayName;`

And call `userGlobals()` method of GlobalProvider class with [**`Provider`**](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for that you need to add this dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`

Then you can provide the GlobalProvider class to the wrapper as follows:
**main.dart**:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './globals_provider.dart';
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalsProvider>.value(
      value: GlobalsProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final globalsProvider = Provider.of<GlobalsProvider>(context);
    globalsProvider.userGlobals();

    final user = Provider.of<ModelUser?>(context);

    //return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

**`Update`** : In your database.dart file, you can create a new instance of the GlobalsProvider class and access the currentUID and currentUsername variables:

```
import './globals_provider.dart';

class Database {
  GlobalsProvider globalsProvider = GlobalsProvider();

  Future<void> someDatabaseFunction() async {
    // Call the userGlobals() method to initialize your required variables
    await globalsProvider.userGlobals();

    // Access the variables
    print(globalsProvider.currentUID);
    print(globalsProvider.currentUsername);
  }
}
```

Reference : [**Provider**](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: Is it possible to use this without a context? I have a `database.dart` file where I define all my functions that query Firebase. I want these functions to receive the most up to date values for `currentUsername` and `currentUID` but the `database.dart` file is not a widget.

Comment: These variables won't ever change throughout the app. Once the user is authenticated, these variables should receive the correct values and then remain unchanged forever until the user logs out.

Comment: Also, this is not working. The variables are showing as empty strings. They are not getting filled.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Hi updated the code as per your requirement ack if that worked for you

Comment: This worked, but is there a way to use this without having to declare `await globalsProvider.userGlobals();` inside every function of my `database.dart` file? I would love to simply declare `GlobalsProvider globalsProvider = GlobalsProvider();` inside the `Database` class like you have in your updated answer and then have that be done. In essence, any function I use in `database.dart` should already have access to any property/method in `GlobalsProvider`.

Comment: The reason I ask is because it's risky to forget to declare `await globalsProvider.userGlobals();` inside each database function because the variables are initialized to empty strings and therefore the app continues to run using empty strings.

Comment: Apologies for late replies. If you need to eliminate `await globalsProvider.userGlobals();` then at this point you can consider to use flutter wrappers such as `GetX` or `Riverpod` which will inject these things for you, But that will also introduce complexity. Hence, I have provided like this.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I'll use it this way then. Thanks for all your help Rohit!